# How to create a Hashtable in javascript from a JSON by setting a value as the key?

Tags: javascript, json, hashtable

I apologize if this is too vague, But I want to search each JSON object by a unique value and then spit out another value. I have been told it would be a good idea to create a Hash Table for this issue, but I do not know how to go about this. For example:

```
{
    "form_key" : "basicPatientName",
    "data" : "Miranda Jones",
    "cid" : 2,
    "pid" : 1,
    "no" : "0"
}
```

I want to search `basicPatientName` and be able to pull `Miranda Jones`, or search basicPatientgender and pull 1.
I used a library called **DefiantJS** which lets me easily loop through my JSON and lets me do exactly what I am asking, but I have been told that there are too many iterations involved if I want to do this 1000+ times in the same program.

Comment: Object literals in JavaScript are as close to hash tables you might be used to in a language like java as you're going to get to in JS without some external library.

Comment: Will you **always** and **only** need to look up by `basicPatientName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this:

```js
data = [{
    "form_key" : "basicPatientName",
    "data" : "Miranda Jones",
    "cid" : 2,
    "pid" : 1,
    "no" : "0"
},
{
    "form_key" : "basicPatientGender",
    "data" : "1",
    "cid" : 4,
    "pid" : 1,
    "no" : "0"
}
];

var result = {};
data.forEach(function (rec) {
    result[rec.form_key] = rec.data;
});

// output result
console.log(result);

// Example look-up use:
var data = result.basicPatientName; //  = Miranda Jones
```

Comment: Thank you so much!